# How to use php curl in searching and outputting from another website?

Tags: php, html, curl

I am a student who is new to the web developing world.Please bare w/ me for having some mistakes and insufficient knowledge.

My question is how can I use php cUrl in this problem, I made a php file that serves as an index or frontpage for another website. What we were ask to do is create a search page then output the result from the search. The user inputs something then it searches on the other website, after that the result will be outputted on some iframes maybe.

Below is my code,

```
<?php
$url = 'http://somesite.com';
{
$username=$_POST['Search'];
$yourformfields="Search=$Search";
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://somesite.com');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$yourformfields);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
//$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);

curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer))
{
    echo"<iframe src='$buffer'></iframe>";
}


}

?>

    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="formName" value="<?=$varName;?>">
    <input type="Submit" name="formSubmit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

what happens is when I input something it does not output the result, honestly it doesn't output anything. I've checked it like 4 or 5 times but because of my current knowledge in web developing and programming I can't seem to find the problem. Appreciate all the help tnx.

Comment: You mean user enter some web page and you should display that webpage or what?

Comment: and you have to post your full code because your code is missing some parts we can't find whats going on untill you post full code or stat your problem properly

Comment: The user will input a postal code, then it should display the result from the other website, w/c in our case we use Iframes for the output

Comment: can you give an example website and example output?

Comment: Example. Input=2000 Output should be the Postcode, Suburbs and the Category. The output comes from the other webiste I just have to output it in my index, so what happens basically is the search for that site was just put to another site.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a good start and iframe is not a good solution in your case try using ajax.

curl.php

```
    <form action="curl.php" method="post">
        URL <input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo ((isset($_POST['url']))?$_POST['url']:"") ?>"> <br>
        Keyword <input type="text" name="keyword" value="<?php echo ((isset($_POST['keyword']))?$_POST['keyword']:"") ?>"> <br>
        <input type="Submit" name="formSubmit" value="Search">
    </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $st = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if($st==200)
       echo "Request Unsuccessful";
    else
    {
        if (strpos($response,$_POST['keyword']) !== false)
        {
            echo 'Your input keyword found.';
        }
        else
            echo 'No matches, try another keyword';
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

**Note:** This code requires that you've enabled `php curl` extension

Comment: let me know if you face problems

Comment: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set - but without this line it works fine for search on the same domain at least